# android studio. При запуске теста не открывается приложение. БЕЗ ОШИБОК

Tags: android, android-studio, junit

[image: как запускаю][image: Результат теста]

Не смотря на то, что тест "прошел" приложение даже не открывалось

Comment: Его как бы в эмуляторе надо запускать

Comment: Тесты запускаются кнопкой Run test же ? Эмулятор при этом может быть запущен

Comment: Так это запуск теста, а не программы

Comment: в тесте же должна и сама программа открыться
Если же программу открыть до теста и запустить его
то программа сворачивается (

Answer (score 0):

Тест - это отдельная программа со своими точками входа.
В списке установленных приложений вы можете найти её как отдельное приложение.
Инструментальный тест тестирует логику кода отдельных методов - для этого не нужно запускать всё приложение, оно будет только мешать.
Достаточно загрузить тестируемый класс и вызвать его метод(ы).
На экран ничего не выведется пока вы не напишите UI-тест.
UI-тесты позволяют запускать компоненты приложения, тыкать по кнопкам, вводить тексты, ... и проверять правильно ли приложение отреагировало.